# How to access Two models data in single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing one problem in asp.net MVC4; I have two model one is Customer and one is Login. I want to see Customers list on CustomerList.cshtml  page and also want to use login's model data, but CustomerList.cshtml page have

```
@model IEnumerable<smetiger.Models.Country>
```

So how can I use Login's model data, actually I want to Login with Validation message. Means Customer's list page should have logged opportunity, But I cannot use two model in one page.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a viewmodel that has 2 properties, one for each model you need to represent

Comment: +1 - just reference a ViewModel class instead that has both models, then populate both inside of your controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some properties from Model1 and Some properties from model2. Then i prefer to create a pseudo(Temporary) class that has properties(Required) from model1 and model2.Then create a view for pseudo and  Then assign the values to pseudo class properties from model1 and model2 in Controller and pass it to Pseudo class view.I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 model in view and use only names for other ations. For example, for Customers use,

```
@model IEnumerable<smetiger.Models.Country>
```

And in same view, for login use just names, not model. (ie. use `TextBox`, not `TextBoxFor`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account"))
{
   @Html.TextBox("email")
   @Html.Password("password")
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```